# Create dynamic query to report number of products per month per company group with totals per product and per company

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

Should create a dynamic pivot table to report products sold monthly by company group.

- There are several products and each company group might have a different combination of them.
- The product status are Active and Cancelled.
- The Active products are counted using the date where they were billed (dbilldate) and the cancelled should be counted using dtContractCancelledDate.
- There are some cases where the company group does not sell or cancel a product during the month so all the column should reflect that (look on Prod2 Cancelled). 
  A calculation column should exist to calculate the net per product (Prod Active – Prod Cancelled).

We need help

•   Creating different calculation to count the product active and cancelled using the corresponding dates (dbilled and dtcancelledbilled)

•   Creating a column with 0s when there are not sold/cancelled products

•   Creating the net columns for each product

•   Creating the subtotals at the end of each column

This is the result desired:

```
  Pd1Actv Pd1Cancd  Pd1Net  Prd2Actv Prd2Cancd  Prd2Net   Total
Comp1    6        5        1       15        0        15       16
Comp2   20        6       14       39        0        39       53
Comp3   63       14       49       82        0        82      131
Total   89       25       64      136        0       136      200
```

This is the main table from where data is extracted

```
SELECT [iCompId],[sContractStatusCode],[sContractStatusDesc],[dBillDate] ,dtContractCancelledBilled  
FROM [Contract_Header]
```

This is what I have until now:

```
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Compgroupnumber as varchar(20),
@startdate as date,
@enddate as date

set @startdate=cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as
date)
set @enddate=DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
set @sCompGroupNumber ='DG10000174'

select @cols = 
STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME(h.sProductCode+'
 '+sContractStatusDesc) 
from [Contract_Header] h
inner join [Comp_Header] d on d.iid=h.icompId
inner join [Comp_CompGroupLink] dgl on d.iId=dgl.CompId
inner join [Comp_DealerGroups] dg on dgl.iCompGroupId=dg.iId
where  (h.sContractStatusCode='A' or h.sContractStatusCode='C') and
(h.dBillDate between @startdate and @enddate)  and
sCompGroupNumber='DG10000174' and 
h.sProductCode in
(                     
  select distinct t.sProductCode
  from [Contract_Header] t
  inner join [Comp_Header] d on d.iid=t.iDealerId
  inner join [Comp_CompGroupLink] dgl on d.iId=dgl.iCompId
  inner join [Comp_CompGroups] dg on dgl.iDealerGroupId=dg.iId
  where  (t.sContractStatusCode='A' or t.sContractStatusCode='C') and
 (t.dBillDate between @startdate and @enddate)  and
  sCompGroupNumber='DG10000174' 
  )FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')

set @query= 
'SELECT sCompName,' + @cols + ' , +Total
 from 
(
select d.sCompName,
 col = c.sProductCode+'' ''+c.sContractStatusDesc,c.sContractStatusCode,
from [Contract_Header] c
 inner join [Comp_Header] d on d.iid=c.iDealerId
 inner join [Comp_CompGroupLink] dgl on d.iId=dgl.iCompId
 inner join [Comp_CompGroups] dg on dgl.iCompGroupId=dg.iId
 where (dBillDate between '''+CAST(@startdate AS varchar)+''' and 
         '''+CAST(@enddate AS VARCHAR)+''') and 
        sCompGroupNumber='''+'DG10000174'+''' and  
        (c.sContractStatusCode='''+'A'+''' or 
         c.sContractStatusCode='''+'C'+''' ) and 
            sproductcode in

            (select distinct sProductCode 
             from [Contract_Header] t 
              inner join [Comp_Header] d on d.iid=t.iCompId
              inner join [Comp_CompGroupLink] dgl on d.iId=dgl.iCompId
              inner join [Comp_CompGroups] dg on dgl.iCompGroupId=dg.iId
              where (dBillDate between '''+CAST(@startdate AS varchar)+''' 
              and '''+CAST(@enddate AS VARCHAR)+''') and             
              (t.sContractStatusCode='''+'A'+''' or 
               t.sContractStatusCode='''+'C'+''' ) and 
               sCompGroupNumber='''+'DG10000174'+''' 
             ) 
      )  as DataSource
        pivot 
        (
            Count(sContractStatusCode)
            for col in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p order by sCompName' 

execute sp_executesql @query
```

This is the result of the query above

```
    Pd1Actv Pd1Cancd Pd2Actv Pd3Actv    
Comp 1    59      0         59     118      
Comp 2    26      1         25      65
```

there are missing the columns when there are not products cancelled for Pd2 and Pd3, the net columns (pdAct-PdCanc), sub total and totals..

Thanks in advance for all the help...

mary

Comment: If your @cols query doesn't return all the headings then change look into changing an Inner join to a left join.

Comment: Yeah, kinda hard to guess what's wrong with all your code without having your data.  But to find where the problems lays, best to break it down into smaller parts. Start with that inner query used to build the cols variable. And yeah, might have something to do with the inner joins. Or because of missing data for those billdates?

Comment: Btw, could it be there's a few mistakes in the joins for the first query? More specific, that `[Comp_DealerGroups] dg on dgl.iCompGroupId=dg.iId`  versus  `[Comp_CompGroups] dg on dgl.iDealerGroupId=dg.iId`. Based on the naming, could it be they should be switched?   Another thing. It might be worth it to first load your data as-is based on the criteria into a temporary #table. Then build your dynamic sql's from that result.  That way you don't have to add any criteria in the sql to generate `@cols`.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. They are appreciated. Is there any way I can attach a file with data, table structure? Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments and sorry for the delay. Here is the information needed: